# Storing current user on a table in backenless

Tags: objective-c, backendless

I want to retrieve the current user and store it on  a table called address but When I run this I don't see the current user in the Backenless table.

```
AddressLines.userid = backendless.userService.currentUser;
```

This is the warning I get on that code:

"Incompatible pointer assining to 'NSString *' from BackendlessUser *' "

Comment: The warning is saying that `backendless.userService.currentUser ` is an instance of `BackendlessUser` and `userid` should be a string. Double check your types.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is saying that `backendless.userService.currentUser` is an instance of `BackendlessUser` and `userid` should be a `NSString`. Double check your types.

You should do this:

`AddressLines.userid = backendless.userService.currentUser.name;`

Answer (score -1):

The "currentUser" property would be set only if there is a currently logged in user.